# Why does this simple Java Swing program freeze?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, concurrency

Below is a simple Java Swing program that consists of two files:

- *Game.java*
- *GraphicalUserInterface.java*

The graphical user interface displays a "New Game" button, followed by three other buttons numbered 1 to 3.

If the user clicks on one of the numbered buttons, the game prints out the corresponding number onto the console. However, if the user clicks on the "New Game" button, the program freezes.

(1) Why does the program freeze?

(2) How can the program be rewritten to fix the problem?

(3) How can the program be better written in general?

### Source

***Game.java***:

```
public class Game {

    private GraphicalUserInterface userInterface;

    public Game() {
        userInterface = new GraphicalUserInterface(this);
    }

    public void play() {
        int selection = 0;

        while (selection == 0) {
            selection = userInterface.getSelection();
        }

        System.out.println(selection);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.play();
    }

}
```

---

***GraphicalUserInterface.java***:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphicalUserInterface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Game game;
    private JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    private JButton[] numberedButtons = new JButton[3];
    private JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    private int selection;
    private boolean isItUsersTurn = false;
    private boolean didUserMakeSelection = false;

    public GraphicalUserInterface(Game game) {
        this.game = game;

        newGameButton.addActionListener(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            numberedButtons[i] = new JButton((new Integer(i+1)).toString());
            numberedButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            southPanel.add(numberedButtons[i]);
        }

        getContentPane().add(newGameButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton pressedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();

        if (pressedButton.getText() == "New Game") {
            game.play();
        }
        else if (isItUsersTurn) {
            selection = southPanel.getComponentZOrder(pressedButton) + 1;
            didUserMakeSelection = true;
        }
    }

    public int getSelection() {
        if (!isItUsersTurn) {
            isItUsersTurn = true;
        }

        if (didUserMakeSelection) {
            isItUsersTurn = false;
            didUserMakeSelection = false;
            return selection;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

---

The problem results from using the `while` loop

```
while (selection == 0) {
    selection = userInterface.getSelection();
}
```

in the `play()` method of *Game.java*.

If lines 12 and 14 are commented out,

```
//while (selection == 0) {
    selection = userInterface.getSelection();
//}
```

the program no longer freezes.

I think the problem is related to concurrency. However, I would like to gain a precise understanding of why the `while` loop causes the program to freeze.

Comment: What is the point of the while loop in that program? It is lagged because that is an infinite loop.

Comment: It is called an infinite loop.

Comment: The point of the `while` loop is to wait for the user to make a selection. The `getSelection()` method returns the number when it is the user's turn.

Answer (score 17):

Thank you fellow programmers. I found the answers very useful.

> (1) Why does the program freeze?

When the program first starts, `game.play()` gets executed by the *main thread*, which is the thread that executes `main`. However, when the "New Game" button is pressed, `game.play()` gets executed by the *event dispatch thread* (instead of the main thread), which is the thread responsible for executing event-handling code and updating the user interface. The `while` loop (in `play()`) only terminates if `selection == 0` evaluates to `false`. The only way `selection == 0` evaluates to `false` is if `didUserMakeSelection` becomes `true`. The only way `didUserMakeSelection` becomes `true` is if the user presses one of the numbered buttons. However, the user cannot press any numbered button, nor the "New Game" button, nor exit the program. The "New Game" button doesn't even pop back out, because the event dispatch thread (which would otherwise repaint the screen) is too busy executing the `while` loop (which is effectively inifinte for the above reasons).

> (2) How can the program be rewritten to fix the problem?

Since the problem is caused by the execution of `game.play()` in the event dispatch thread, the direct answer is to execute `game.play()` in another thread. This can be accomplished by replacing

```
if (pressedButton.getText() == "New Game") {
    game.play();
}
```

with

```
if (pressedButton.getText() == "New Game") {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            game.play();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

However, this results in a new (albeit more tolerable) problem: Each time the "New Game" button is pressed, a new thread is created. Since the program is very simple, it's not a big deal; such a thread becomes inactive (i.e. a game finishes) as soon as the user presses a numbered button. However, suppose it took longer to finish a game. Suppose, while a game is in progress, the user decides to start a new one. Each time the user starts a new game (before finishing one), the number of active threads increments. This is undesirable, because each active thread consumes resources.

The new problem can be fixed by:

(1) adding import statements for `Executors`, `ExecutorService`, and `Future`, in *Game.java*

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
```

(2) adding a *single-thread executor* as a field under `Game`

```
private ExecutorService gameExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

(3) adding a `Future`, representing the last task submitted to the *single-thread executor*, as a field under `Game`

```
private Future<?> gameTask;
```

(4) adding a method under `Game`

```
public void startNewGame() {
    if (gameTask != null) gameTask.cancel(true);
    gameTask = gameExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            play();
        }
    });
}
```

(5) replacing

```
if (pressedButton.getText() == "New Game") {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            game.play();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

with

```
if (pressedButton.getText() == "New Game") {
    game.startNewGame();
}
```

and finally,

(6) replacing

```
public void play() {
    int selection = 0;

    while (selection == 0) {
        selection = userInterface.getSelection();
    }

    System.out.println(selection);
}
```

with

```
public void play() {
    int selection = 0;

    while (selection == 0) {
        selection = userInterface.getSelection();
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(selection);
}
```

To determine where to put the `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` check, look at where the method lags. In this case, it is where the user has to make a selection.

There is another problem. The main thread could still be active. To fix this, you can replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.play();
}
```

with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.startNewGame();
}
```

The code below applies the above modifications (in addition to a `checkThreads()` method):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game {
    private GraphicalUserInterface userInterface;
    private ExecutorService gameExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Future<?> gameTask;

    public Game() {
        userInterface = new GraphicalUserInterface(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkThreads();
        Game game = new Game();
        checkThreads();
        game.startNewGame();
        checkThreads();
    }

    public static void checkThreads() {
        ThreadGroup mainThreadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        ThreadGroup systemThreadGroup = mainThreadGroup.getParent();

        System.out.println("\n" + Thread.currentThread());
        systemThreadGroup.list();
    }

    public void play() {
        int selection = 0;

        while (selection == 0) {
            selection = userInterface.getSelection();
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(selection);
    }

    public void startNewGame() {
        if (gameTask != null) gameTask.cancel(true);
        gameTask = gameExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                play();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GraphicalUserInterface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private Game game;
    private JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    private JButton[] numberedButtons = new JButton[3];
    private JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    private int selection;
    private boolean isItUsersTurn = false;
    private boolean didUserMakeSelection = false;

    public GraphicalUserInterface(Game game) {
        this.game = game;

        newGameButton.addActionListener(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            numberedButtons[i] = new JButton((new Integer(i+1)).toString());
            numberedButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            southPanel.add(numberedButtons[i]);
        }

        getContentPane().add(newGameButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton pressedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();

        if (pressedButton.getText() == "New Game") {
            game.startNewGame();
            Game.checkThreads();
        }
        else if (isItUsersTurn) {
            selection = southPanel.getComponentZOrder(pressedButton) + 1;
            didUserMakeSelection = true;
        }
    }

    public int getSelection() {
        if (!isItUsersTurn) {
            isItUsersTurn = true;
        }

        if (didUserMakeSelection) {
            isItUsersTurn = false;
            didUserMakeSelection = false;
            return selection;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

References

[The Java Tutorials: Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)
[The Java Tutorials: Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
[The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)
[The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Second Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html)
[Eckel, Bruce. *Thinking in Java, 4th Edition*. "Concurrency & Swing: Long-running tasks", p. 988.](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4)
[How do I cancel a running task and replace it with a new one, on the same thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684927/how-do-i-cancel-a-running-task-and-replace-it-with-a-new-one-on-the-same-thread)

Comment: Really nice solution! The use of `Executor` and `Future` avoids having the interface frozen. +1

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough this problem does not have to do with concurrency, although your program is fraught with issues in that respect as well:

- `main()` is launched in the main application thread
- Once `setVisible()` is called in a Swing component, a new thread is created to handle the user interface
- Once a user presses the `New Game` button, the *UI thread* (*not* the main thread) calls, via the `ActionEvent` listener the `Game.play()` method, which goes into an infinite loop: the UI thread is constantly polling its own fields via the `getSelection()` method, without ever being given the chance to continue working on the UI and any new input events from the user.

  Essentially, you are polling a set of fields from the same thread that is supposed to change them - a guaranteed infinite loop that keeps the Swing event loop from getting new events or updating the display.

You need to re-design your application:

- It seems to me that the return value of `getSelection()` can only change after some user action. In that case, there is really no need to poll it - checking *once* in the UI thread should be enough.
- For very simple operations, such as a simple game that only updates the display after the user does something, it may be enough to perform all calculations in the event listeners, without any responsiveness issues.
- For more complex cases, e.g. if you need the UI to update without user intervention, such as a progress bar that fills-up as a file is downloaded, you need to do your actual work in separate threads and use [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) to coordinate the UI updates.

Answer (score 1):

> (3) How can the program be better written in general?

I've refactored your code a little, and guessed that you might like to turn it into a guessing game.  I'll explain some of the refactorings:

First, there is no need for a game loop, the user interface provides this by default.  Next, for swing apps you should really place components onto the event queue, as I have done with invokeLater. Action listeners should really be anonymous inner classes unless there is a reason to reuse them, as it keeps the logic encapsulated.

I hope this serves as a good example for you to finish writing whatever game you wanted.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game {

    private int prize;
    private Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new UserInterface(new Game()));
    }

    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Please Select a number...");
        prize = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
    }

    public void buttonPressed(int button) {
        String message = (button == prize) ? "you win!" : "sorry, try again";
        System.out.println(message);

    }
}

class UserInterface implements Runnable {

    private final Game game;

    public UserInterface(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        newGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                game.play();
            }
        });

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            final JButton button = new JButton("" + i);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    game.buttonPressed(Integer.parseInt(button.getText()));
                }
            });
            southPanel.add(button);
        }

        frame.add(newGameButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event callback is executed in the GUI event processing thread (Swig is single threaded). You can't get any other event while in the callback so your while loop never gets terminated. This is not to consider the fact that in java a variable accessed from multiple threads should be either volatile or atomic or protected with synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 0):

What I observed is that initially didUserMakeSelection is false. So Its alway returning 0 when called from while loop and control will remain keep looping in while loop.