# How do I cancel a running task and replace it with a new one, on the same thread?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I would like to cancel a running task and replace it with a new one, on the same thread.

In the code below, I used a *single-thread executor* to start a new task and capture a `Future` representing it. I then used the `Future` to cancel the task. However, the task did not cancel.

1. Why does my code not work?
2. How do I cancel a running task and replace it with a new one, on the same thread?

Example code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("New task started");
        int i = 0; while (true) i++;
    }
}

public class TaskLauncher extends JFrame {
    private JButton button = new JButton("Start new task");
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Future<?> future;

    public TaskLauncher() {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (future != null) future.cancel(true);
                future = executor.submit(new Task());
            }
        });

        add(button);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TaskLauncher();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code inside the `actionPerformed` method gets executed?

Comment: why do you want the replacement to run on the same thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just calling cancel on the Future object will not cause the task to stop. See the API docs for more information. Also check this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418033/java-executors-how-can-i-stop-submitted-tasks) which shows how you have to code your task so that it can be cancelled using the Future object.

Modify your task like this:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("New task started");
        int i = 0; 
        while (true) {
            i++;
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Exiting gracefully");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's incorrect! you should call the isInterrupted() method *not* intrrupted() as it'll reset the interrupt flag. I prefer to write into it into the while, ie, while (!Thread.isInterrupted()) then you can avoid the multiple branch returns and condition check above...

Comment: How does resetting the interrupt flag affect OP's solution? Also note that isInteruppted() is an instance method so Thread.isInterrupted() is wrong. I agree the test could be part of while instead of a separate if.

Comment: my mistake, it should be while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()). calling intrrupted() isn't incorrect for OPs problem, I should have been clearer that its generally bad practice but not necessarily incorrect.